# How to manage cascading GUI changes in winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, user-interface, design-patterns

In the application I'm working on, there are a lot of dependencies between GUI fields. For example, when the user changes the value in a textbox, other controls on the form need to change based on the new value, which in turn may or may not trigger other changes on the form. These relationships can get arbitrarily complicated, and user requirements change frequently.

I know there are patterns such as MVC to separate out business logic into a controller, but I think the problem I'm trying to solve is different, because it is the logic itself that gets complicated. It seems the relationships can be modeled as a directed graph with each GUI control being a node. I was wondering if this was the right way to approach it and if there are any frameworks out there before I try rolling my own.

Comment: Restating your question is: 'I want an external [thing] to encapsulate the Logic and update GUI based on changing data'.  The answer to that question is what MVC frameworks are for - or Gnostus' suggestion below.

Comment: I don't want that. I want an external thing to handle dependencies between object states. I shouldn't have mentioned GUI at all. It is just a specific case of what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

We use an 'Appearance Model' to have the controller update the state of that model, and the view updates itself based on the appearance model only.

```
MyAppModel.MyControl.Readonly = true;
```

that would be bound to a controls readonly property on the view.

so now based on some event I can flick these states on /off to change the view.

Comment: That is pretty clever. But, maybe my question wasn't clear, since I'm trying to figure out how to manage event propagation in the GUI rather than how to use MVC.

Comment: I would recommend not making the GUI smart in that sense, and rather extract it out to a controller, but I could recommend Reactive Framework as we just adopted it and it works miracles with event management if you are familiar with Linq.